# How to put an iframe behind a div, then when a button is clicked, it will appear over the div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make a webpage where a user would click a button then an iframe behind a div would pop up and appear over the div?

My sample code goes like this:

```
<style>
#myiframe {
   position: absolute; 
   display:none; }
</style>
 <script = "text/javascript">
 function showIFrame() {  
  var iframe = document.getElementById("myiframe");  
  iframe.style.display="block";  
 }  
 </script>
<div class="custom" style="margin-top:17px;margin-bottom:17px;" >
<table>
<tr valign="top">
<td style="max-width: 715px;">
    <div id="error" class="err" style="margin-bottom:8px;"></div>
    <div id="cavas_id<?php echo $module->id; ?>" class="bt-googlemaps"  style="border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
```

```
 <form name="search" id="search" method="get" action="crime_map/map_crime.php" target="carsearch">
 <button id="SearchCarButton" class="submitBtn" onclick="showIFrame()"/>  <span>Crime Map</span></button></form>
```

I plan to overlap the iframe div (cavos) over the div (cavas) when the Crime Map button is clicked. How can I do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you just hide the div?

Comment: Nah, the div with the cavos is with a google map, and the cavas div is also a page with a google map. Both needs to be able to be navigated.